# Sum of items of a class

Tags: python, class, addition

What I have to do is to create a class that counts from a giving single argument and itself make the arithmetical operation.

```
class Counts:
    def __init__(self, value=0):
        self.value = value
        
    def newvalue(self, other):
        return Counts(self.value + other)
```

But for every I make to the code I got any different error, either syntax or callable argument.

The idea is to get

`Counts()`

Expected output

`0`

Next

`Counts.newvalue(10)`

Expected output

`10`

Next

`Counts.newvalue(40)`

Expected output

`50`

Next

`Counts.newvalue(-17)`

Expected output

`33`

And so on.

Comment: `print(Counts().newvalue(10).newvalue(40).newvalue(-17).value)` works fine. What is the error you're referring to?

Comment: Please, provide the code you've tried that gives you errors and the whole traceback

Comment: This smells like homework... @Felipe your class definition is fine. How are you calling your function?

Comment: OP's question is fairly clear. He wants a class defined such that `Counts()` returns 0, not `<__main__.Counts at 0x12345678>`. I don't understand why this got flagged with _This question needs details or clarity_.

Comment: This is not identical to, but very similar, to two recent questions involving constructs allowing things like `x(0)(1)(2)(3) == 6`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that shows the expected behaviour is

```
class Counts:
    value = 0
    def __new__(self):
        return self.value
    
    @classmethod
    def newvalue(cls, other):
        cls.value += other
        return cls.value
```

however this is a somewhat strange piece of code, as you are creating a class that returns a value when initialized instead of an object deriving from that class by overriding `__new__`, which is pretty non-standard.

also if you want to zero the value whenever `Count()` is called, you can add a `self.value = 0` before the `return self.value`

Tests ->

```
print(Counts())
print(Counts.newvalue(10))
print(Counts.newvalue(40))
print(Counts.newvalue(-17))
```

returns

```
0
10
50
33
```